# Integrating $\int_{0}^{2} (1-x)^2 dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I solved this  integral

$$\int_{0}^{2} (1-x)^2 dx$$

by operating the squared binomial, first.

But, I found in some book, that it arrives at the same solution and I don't understand why it appears a negative simbol. This is the author solution:

$$\int_{0}^{2} (1-x)^2 dx = -\frac{1}{3}(-x+1)^3|_{0}^{2}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: What's the derivative of $\frac13(-x+1)^3$? (Remember to use the chain rule!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{2} (1-x)^2 dx = F(x) |_{0}^{2}$$

while we should have $\frac{\partial{F(x)}}{\partial x} = (1-x)^2$. It is easy to show that (especially if you set $u=x-1$ and then using chain rule):

$$
F(x) = - \frac{1}{3} (1-x)^3 \Rightarrow \frac{\partial{F(x)}}{\partial x} = (1-x)^2
$$

so basically that minus sign is because of negative sign of $x$ inside the parenthesis.

Comment: It is not necessary to change the up and down limits when I set $u=1-x$?

Comment: After changing to $u$ and taking the integral, you can change back to $x$, so in this case you don't need to change the limit.

Answer (score 1):

If $u = 1- x$ then $du = -1 \dot \ dx = -dx$. Thus

$$\int_{1}^{-1} -u^2 \,du =-\int_{1}^{-1} u^2\, du  =\int_{-1}^{1} u^2\, du$$

Comment: I understand why someone might write $-(u^2)$ in some contexts, or $(-u^2)$ in others, even though there is a standard convention that makes the parentheses in the former unnecessary, but why write $-(u)^2$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Just to remind the student of the substitution made, $(1 - x)^2 =(u)^2$. But as you said, is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant where I can find the integral property of switching the endpoints. I didn't know, and couldn't find. It seems logic.

Comment: @Isai I've seen this as  a convention, in my analysis course.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Although the convention is logic, but I've never seen in books. I'm sorry for my ignorance. can I find in any book?

Comment: I've updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: I've studied with "Curso de Análise - Vol 1 - Elon Lages Lima" which (unfortunately or not) is in portuguese, Elon is a great professor though, internationally recognized. There I'm pretty sure you'd find it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^2(1-x)^2\, dx = \int_{-1}^1x^2\,dx$$
Note the negative appears, but you get rid of this by switching the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where you need to be careful about the sign. The first place is when you make the derivative of the substitution (if your substitution is 1-x = t, then after making the derivative you get -dx = dt). The second place is when you change the limits of the integration due to the substitution. The lower limit becomes 1 and the upper limit becomes -1. You can find a complete solution to this problem here

http://www.e-academia.cz/solved-math-problems/definite-integral-with-substitution.php

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You may find our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful to learn how to (easily) typeset math here.